# Four coplanar points in $\mathbb{N}^3$ space

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, natural-numbers

Is it possible to write out natural number coordinates of four three-dimensional points $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d} \in \mathbb{N}^3$, with the following determinant zero?

$$\left\vert
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a_x - d_x & a_y - d_y & a_z - d_z \\
  b_x - d_x & b_y - d_y & b_z - d_z \\
  c_x - d_x & c_y - d_y & c_z - d_z
\end{array}
\right\vert$$

**REFINED:**

Dihedral angle with any coordinate plane should not been the multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Any 3 points should not lies on line.

Comment: Sure: $(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0)$.

Comment: @vadim123 Mmmm). Small refinement: dihedral angle with any coordinate plane is not multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Still sure:  $(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4)$

Comment: @RossMillikan what about the last statement? (Sorry for plenty of editions, but I could not formulate the problem immediately).

Comment: How about $(0,0,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,2)$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Zeros are not permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this satisfies what you are looking for:  $(3,2,1),(1,1,1),(2,1,0),(0,0,0)$  Your matrix is then $$\left\vert
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3&2&1 \\
 1&1&1 \\
 2&1&0
\end{array}
\right\vert=0$$ as the bottom two rows add to the top one.

Comment: Whole numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ are strictly positive things.

Comment: You can add one to each coordinate of each point, producing the same matrix.  It should be clear how to make such a matrix by now.  Make your favorite $3 \times 3$ singular matrix.  Let $d=(1,1,1)$ Solve for the other three points.  Done.